# Gridview item programmatically from xml code

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I want to add views (in this example, ImageViews) to a grid layout programmatically. My grid is fixed to 5 columns and 7 rows (35 items in total) and I don't want to add these 35 views in my xml so I want to do it programmatically. I'm struggling to find a conversion from xml to java/kotlin code for the attributes `layout_width`, `layout_height`, `layout_columnWeight` and `layout_rowWeight` so that the layout looks exactly the same as if I have defined the views in the xml. Can someone write the code for the views' layoutparams that matches these attributes?

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:columnCount="5"
    android:rowCount="7">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera"/>

        ... //35 times the Image view

</GridLayout>
```

The previous xml would give me the next layout:
[image: expectation]

I tried the next one without success (Imageviews are showing too big and not fitting all inside the grid boundaries):

```
    for(i in 1..35) {
        val view = ImageView(context)
        val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED, GridLayout.FILL,1f),
            GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f))
        view.layoutParams = params
        gridView.addView(view, 0)
    }
```

[image: imageview showing too big and not fitting inside the grid boundaries]

Can you help me translate the xml into java/kotlin code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First step would be to create a view object

```
val image = ImageView()
image.setImageResource(resourceID)
```

Then you'll need to set layout attributes

```
val params = GridLayout.LayoutParams(x, y)
//x and y is your size, if you want something special you can do for instance LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
```

You can also set size a bit later:

```
params.height = X
params.width = Y
```

Lastly you just add the view to the layout

```
gridView.addView(image)
```

Put that all inside a `for` loop and you're done. `GridView` would take care of placing the views.

Answer (score 0):

Result :

[image]

Try something like this :

```
    final int MAX_COLUMN = gridView.getColumnCount(); //5
    final int MAX_ROW = gridView.getRowCount(); //7
    final int itemsCount = MAX_ROW * MAX_COLUMN; //35

    int row = 0, column = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++) {
        ImageView view = new ImageView(this);

        //Just to provide alternate colors
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(GridLayout.spec(row, 1F), GridLayout.spec(column, 1F));
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
        gridView.addView(view);

        column++;

        if (column >= MAX_COLUMN) {
            column = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }
```

If you want specific width and height for your cells, then use :

```
     params.width = 100; // Your width
     params.height = 100; //your height
```